# Как добавить полосу прогресса ProgressBar?

Tags: c#, wpf

Внутри `string[] FileNames` файлы для архивации. К ним можно как-то счётчик приделать.

```
        var cmpr = new SevenZipCompressor();

        cmpr.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Fast;
        //cmpr.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.SevenZip;

        if (File.Exists(FullNameArchive) == true)
        {
            cmpr.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Append;
        }
        else { cmpr.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create; }

        //cmpr.CompressDirectory(@"путь\к\пакуемой\папке", @"имя\архива");
        cmpr.CompressFiles(FullNameArchive, FileNames);
```

.

```
<ProgressBar Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: А `SevenZipCompressor` даёт сообщения о прогрессе операции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Официальный пример кода можно подсмотреть [на CodePlex](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SevenZipTestWPF/MainWindow.xaml.cs). Поскольку CodePlex скоро закрывается, вот выжимка:

```
// модель
double progress;
double Progress
{
    get => progress;
    set
    {
        if (progress != value)
        {
            progress = value;
            // отправляете нотификацию об изменении прогресса
        }
    }
}
```

```
Progress = 0;
cmpr.Compressing += OnCompressingProgress;
cmpr.CompressionFinished += OnCompressionFinished;
cmpr.BeginCompressFiles(...); // асинхронная операция
```

```
void OnCompressingProgress(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e) =>
    Progress += e.PercentDelta / 100.0;

void OnCompressionFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Progress = 1.0;
    var cmpr = (SevenZipCompressor)sender;
    cmpr.Compressing -= OnCompressingProgress;
    cmpr.CompressionFinished -= OnCompressionFinished;
}
```

На VM-уровне вам надо подписаться на нотификации от модели, возможно, смаршаллировать их в UI-поток, и обновлять INPC-свойство `CompressionProgress`. (Это другое свойство, не то, которое в модели!)

На уровне View вы просто привязываетесь к свойству `CompressionProgress` из VM:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding CompressionProgress}" Minimum="0" Maximum="1"/>
```

Как бы всё.

Comment: не работает. что-то ещё нужно?

Comment: Всё это размещать обязательно в 
.xaml.cs или можно влюбом классе?

Comment: @codename0082016: Ээээ... Что означает «не работает»? Давайте код в студию.

Comment: @codename0082016: Модельную часть надо размещать в модельном слое вашего приложения. VM-часть — в VM-слое, UI-часть в UI-слое. Это по идее не просто разные классы, а малосвязанные части приложения. Вы ведь используете паттерн MVVM, да?

Comment: где должен быть расположен CompressionProgress? Value="{Binding CompressionProgress}"

Comment: @codename0082016: В VM-классе. Привязка по идее идёт к VM.

Comment: @codename0082016: А, я понял, у меня было свойство `CompressionProgress` и в модели, и в VM. Для понятности переименовал свойство в модели в просто `Progress`.

Comment: Работает только если добавить pbar.Value = progress;

Comment: @codename0082016: А откуда у вас `progress` оказался в UI-уровне? Это же модель.

Comment: всё это добавлено в .xaml.cs Куда нужно было?

Comment: @codename0082016: Приложение нужно разделить на слои: модель, VM и UI. Исходя из вашего вопроса, вы этого не сделали. Архивацией UI-код заниматься **не должен**.